# Apache shows general root index rather than DocumentRoot index configured with Virtual Host in Debian

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, virtualhost

I have multiple websites supposed to run each with its own domain (e.g. `site1.com`, `differentsite2.com`, `othersite3.com` etc.).
The operative directories of each website are dedicated subfolder in `/var/www/html/`

e.g.

```
/var/www/html/site1
/var/www/html/site2
/var/www/html/site3
```

The virtual host for each website is something like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site1.com
    ServerAlias www.site1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1
    <Directory /var/www/html/site1>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

with a dedicated config file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`
enabled with `a2ensite` command
and the default config disabled with `a2dissite 000-default.conf`

others website are configured in a similar way with

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site2.com
    ServerAlias www.site2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site2
</VirtualHost>
```

etc.

**Problem:**

When I open `www.site1.com` rather than showing index in its `DocumentRoot` at `/var/www/html/site1/index` as supposed,
It shows the index in main root at `/var/www/html/index`

Could someone help he to understand the issue?

Comment: Can you also provide the output from the logs?

Comment: You may want to use mod_info to show you the server configuration, to be sure the VirtualHost directives are being processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was caused by the fact Apache server was configured on port 8080 and Nginx on port 80 so when I invoked the site on port 80 the invocation was processed by Nginx.

Comment: Can you mark this answer as the accepted solution? Perhaps include a few commands and their output which you used to troubleshoot and determine this root cause.

Comment: @Simba yes but StackExchange needs some time before allow me to mark the accepted answer.